# Getting 'GET /static/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1795' error for static files

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, backend

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I have `STATIC_URL = '/static/' STATICFILES_DIR = [str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('static'))]` under my settings.py. Here is an image to my current file structure https://pasteboard.co/K3uhtSN.png I linked with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}">` in base.html and loaded at the very top using `{% load static %}` Thank you

Comment: Did you add to your url patterns for static files: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Comment: My book doesn't ask me to do that. Isn't STATICFILES_DIRS in settings.py enough?

Comment: No, Django doesn't normally serve static files but it provides a function to serve that during development (you have to add it to the urlpatterns). Note: It won't work in production (`DEBUG = False`) and you will have to serve static files using nginx apache, etc.

Comment: still doesnt work even after ```from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),

] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
``` it now gives `1896` code error

Comment: I fixed it by copying settings.py from official repo https://github.com/wsvincent/djangoforbeginners/blob/master/ch5-blog-app/

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, but it solved by writing "staticfiles_dirs" like this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = ((os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')), )
```

Comment: where did you write it? Im guessing settings.py

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. If you had created a 'staticfiles' folder or directory during production then be sure to run `python manage.py collectstatic` in your command prompt or terminal.